# Use Python syntax highlighting for [micropython]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Can we add Python syntax highlighting for questions tagged [micropython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/micropython)?

Some random examples of questions when this would be helpful:

- [Update screen every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028287/update-screen-every-hour)
- [Why isn't my ILI9488 touchscreen working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77091126/why-isnt-my-ili9488-touchscreen-working)

Comment: Looks better already. Easy to fix or undo so if it ends up causing issues elsewhere just give a shout.